# Видео на всю ширину страницы в Adobe Muse

Tags: html, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток. Я столкнулся с такой проблемой: не могу растянуть видео на всю ширину страницы в Adobe Muse. Я пользовался вставкой видео с помощью сайта videojs.com. Видео показывается в полную ширину но при изменении ширины окна браузера появляются черные полосы. Хочу сделать так как на этом сайте pidkova.zp.ua. Что можете посоветовать? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно просто, например, при импорте видео с ютуба код будет иметь следующий вид:

Нужно изменить значения параметров width и height в проценты. То есть, указав 100% для значения width и растянув фрейм на всю ширины рабочего поля в Muse видео будет  вести себя как "резиновое", получиться такой код:

не плохой форум с вопросами и ответами [ТуТ](http://adobemuse.ru/topic/84-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83/).